# Empty e Append não retornam nenhum valor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou com o problema que meu empty().append(); não retorna nenhum valor do php na div e também não consigo inserir nada dentro dela, mesmo dentro do próprio html. É como se ela ficasse se apagando, mas por um segundo eu vejo que o conteúdo digitado em HTML está lá, mas ele some novamente. Alguém pode me ajudar?

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sala <?=$nick?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color: #1C1C1C;" onload="carregaMensagem()">

<div class="container">
    <div id="mensagens">
    </div>

    <form onsubmit="enviar(); return false" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem" class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" style="display:none;">
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
    require_once("inc/config.php"); //conexão com banco

    if (isset($_SESSION['nickname'])) {
        $sql = msql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagem");
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            while ($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                echo '<p>Seja Bem vindo'.$_SESSION['nickname'].'</p>';
                echo '<p>Digita /sair deslogar do chat</p>';
                $nick = strip_tags($ln['nickname']);
                $mensagem = htmlspecialchars($ln['mensagem']);
                echo "<p>".$nick.":".$mensagem."</p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p>Seja Bem vindo'.$_SESSION['nickname'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>Digita /sair deslogar do chat</p>';
            echo "Nenhuma mensagem até o momento.";
        }

    } else {
        require_once("inc/nick.php"); // pede pra definir nick
    }
?>
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY

```
function carregaMensagem() {

    var url = "verMensagem.php";
    jQuery.get(url, function(data){
        setInterval(intervaloMsg(data), 3000);

    }); 
}

function intervaloMsg(dados){
    $("#mensagens").empty().append(dados);
    //$("#mensagens").html(dados);

}

function enviar() {
    var url = "enviarMensagem.php";
    var mensagem = $("#mensagem").val();

    var enviando = $.post(url,{mensagem:mensagem});
    console.log(mesangem);
}
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos e peço desculpa se houver algum erro.

Comment: Pode esquecer a parte do  enviar(); Eu acabei dei uma continuada no código mesmo aquela parte não funcionando, mas mesmo sem o enviar(); não aparece nada. Ele deveria me retornar na tela echo '<p>Seja Bem vindo'.$_SESSION['nickname'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>Digita /sair deslogar do chat</p>';
            echo "Nenhuma mensagem até o momento.";
Mas não me retorna nada.

Comment: Sim, depois percebi que o seu problema era o aviso inicial não ser exibido. Mas publiquei uma resposta, veja se é aquilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o erro está nessa linha:

```
$sql = msql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagem");
```

O correto seria

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagem");
```

Também tem um erro no javascript

```
console.log(mesangem);
```

O correto seria

```
console.log(mensagem);
```

Comment: Poxa eu dei bobeira, muito obrigada amigo. Preciso trocar meus óculos kkk

Comment: Rs. Era isso mesmo? Funcionou?

Comment: Funcionou, mas agora estou presa em outra parte. Eu não consigo dar insert no banco kkk

Comment: Marca essa resposta como correta e abre outra pergunta com seu novo problema pra eu tentar ajudar.